# Sharing Tridion content with Third party application

Tags: dxa, web8.5, discovery-service, cil

We are working on couple of new websites using SDL Web 8.5 (Entire team is new to SDL Web 8.5 architecture) during development phase client requested us to make a provision to share published content with their vendor applications, or Intranet applications (which are currently not built using SDL Tridion).  So the question is , 
1) Can we use discovery services to share the published content? ( in 2013 we had oData but not sure something similar to that is present in Web 8.5)
2) Can we use CIL or DXA to share the content?

What we are thinking of is to build a custom API's/rest services using CIL/DXA and share the content in xml format, but not sure if that is the best approach.  In SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 we used to share it using oData.

Comment: CIS (the new WebServices) are based on OData - so you still have that. For content queries, the V2 service (which is approximately the same that existed in 2013) is used, so you may be able to use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nuno commented, you can still get access to the raw data using the (public) OData V2 endpoint (CIS Content Service).

Alternatively, you can get access to your DXA View Model data formatted as JSON (try adding `?format=json` to the URL of a DXA Page).

Comment: Thanks for reply Rick.  As per your suggestion we should go for out of the box DXA or CIS implementation and consume the published content.  It is not really necessary to build one more layer of custom Rest service on top of CIS/DXA. Of course we need to build it, if we want to change format or add some additional tags before we share the content.

Comment: Indeed. DXA is already a (highly customizable) layer on top of CIS.  If you use DXA, you can use custom View Models and custom Controllers to enrich the data coming from CM. You could also implement your custom formatter if you want XML format per se. DXA comes with JSON, Atom (JSON/XML) and RSS (XML) formatters OOTB.

Comment: See http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-DF3BDC77-0343-452F-BBB9-9CBA05021183